# Problemas para salvar informação em uma coluna do banco de dados

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, conexão

Eu preciso pegar uma informação digitada e dar o uptade em um campo (pont), mas o campo precisa ser na mesma linha de um jogador selecionado no meu combobox(cmbtime). Assim quando eu selecionasse o jogador no combobox eu já conseguiria atribuir a pontuação ao jogador selecionado no combobox.

```
$pont = $_POST['pont'];
$id = $_POST['cmbjogador'];
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE jogador SET $pont WHERE cmbjogador );
```

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faltou especificar o nome das colunas como o novo valor e qual é a coluna da condição.

mude:

```
UPDATE jogador SET $pont WHERE cmbjogador
```

Para

```
UPDATE jogador SET pontuacao = $pont WHERE id = $id
```

Não esqueça de colocar o mysql_error() para pegar a mensagem de erro caso aconteça.

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE jogador SET pontuacao = $pont WHERE id = $id") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: valeeeeu, ajudou muito!!!

Answer (score 1):

voce esqueceu de passar o campo da table na query

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE jogador SET campoTabela=$pont WHERE cmbjogador= $id );
```

Comment: valeeeeu, ajudou muito!!!